# how to use join in three tables

Tags: mysql

we have three tables.

```
tblA

id(PK)      doc_id(fk)     mr_id(fk)       date 
--------    ----------     --------        ---------
1             23            22             2012-05-23
2             24            22             2012-05-23
3             25            21             2012-05-24
4             26            22             2012-05-24



tblB 

doc_id(PK)      d_name          d_segId(FK)    mr_id(FK)  
------------    -------------   ----------     ---------- 
     1          manish           1              12
     23         rahul            2              22
     24         paul             1              22
     25         jacky            1              21
     26         amit             2              22



tblC
seg_id(PK)      seg_name       seg_color        
--------        ----------     --------       
1               A_corei         red             
2               Bcorec          green
```

what i want is all the record from tblA where mr_id=22 and date='2012-05-23' and order by seg_name in tblC

doc_id is referenced to tblB and 
on the basis of doc_id, Seg_id is referenced to tblC how to use join in this situation.

It should look like

```
id           doc_id      d_name        seg_color
--------    ---------   ---------      ----------
1            23          rahul         green  
2            24          paul          red
```

Comment: It may be none of my business but I think that your SQL architecture is wrong if you have to use double join to get that simple information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    tblA.id,
    tblA.doc_id,
    tblB.d_name,
    tblC.seg_color
FROM
    tblA, tblB, tblC
WHERE
    tblA.doc_id = tblB.doc_id
    AND
    tblB.d_segId = tblC.seg_id
    AND
    tblA.mr_id = 22
    AND
    tblA.date = '2012-05-23'
ORDER BY
    tblC.seg_name
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
SELECT a.id,b.doc_id,b.d_name,c.seg_color FROM tblB b 
INNER JOIN tblA a ON b.doc_id=a.doc_id
INNER JOIN tblC c ON b.d_segId=c.seg_id
WHERE a.mr_id=22
AND a.date='2012-05-23'
```